# What's the most efficient way to compare these two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I run into a common problem, and I'd like to know a better way to go about it.

Say I have a list or array of ints:

```
var ids = new List<int>();
// pretend I populate 5 or 6 integers
```

And I have a class of cars I pull from the database like this:

```
var cars = carRepo.GetAll();
```

And of course, let's say the Car class has an Id property. It *feels* as if I should be able to do something better than just looping through cars and checking it against the ids. Like there's some sort of fancy Aggregate() or Select() statement that can get what I want. Is there? This is a pretty common thing I run into all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by compare but if you are trying to see in the `cars` collection has all the ids from your `List<int>`, you can do this

```
var result = cars.All(c => ids.Contains(c.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

All is a boolean check that all items in the collection match you want Where....

```
carRepo.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a simple [**Inner Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) to select all cars with an ID in the list of IDs:

```
var query = from car in cars
            join id in ids on car.Id equals id
            select car;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = cars.Where(car => ids.Contains(car.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
bool isEqual = ids.Count == cars.Count && cars.All(car=>ids.Contains(car.Id));
```